# Convert git rm to git rm --cached

Tags: git

I'm cleaning up binary files in a Git repo and I have a long list of files I removed with `git rm`.

Given the scale of the change (7000+ files) I'm now thinking it's more prudent to have used `git rm --cached` instead.

The files are in staging, how do I put them back on disk while keeping them out of git ?

I'm looking for a git command to do this, I'd like to avoid some nasty script hack where I `git co` then `git rm --cached` each file. Once I check them out I won't know which ones I need to delete again and I'd have to redo my work. It's a long list of specific subdirectories, not a straightforward case of rm -r *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just commit your staged deletions and then you could retrieve files from historical commit by `git checkout HEAD~1 -- .`, where you could replace `.` with a path(s) you want to retrieve.

Comment: That's where I am now, I have a list of staged changes I need to push, keeping the affected files on disk but out of git

Comment: @blackbird57 The files are in history "forever" (unless you explicitly alter the history). Even after commit+push you could get it out of the repository using `checkout` anytime.

Comment: So there's no advantage in removing binary files out of git other than a cleaner repo ?

Comment: @blackbird57 `git rm` doesn't remove files from a git _repo_, it deletes them from _working copy_.

Comment: @blackbird57 No, especially if you don't do force pushes. "push" just sends commits to another repository, history is immutable.

Answer (score 0):

To clean up your repo you should use :
https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

### [image]

To get your files you simply checkout the desired commit and it will checkout the files to your working directory.

Comment: I want to avoid checking them out, once they're out I won't know which ones I need to delete again and I'd have to redo my work. It's a long list of specific subdirectories, not just a case of rm -r *

Comment: I thought you want to keep a copy of the files you remove, f not simply use the bfg tool and it will do the job for you,

Comment: I want to remove them from git while keeping them on disk, hence `git rm --cached` but I've used `git rm` so now they're no longer on disk

Comment: You can move them from git and have them on disk if you not checking them out.Where will they be stored?

Comment: I just need to keep the files where they are `/path/to/some/file` but remove them from git and push those changes

Comment: Ok so in this case you can remove them from head and then set the `--assume unchanged flag` and commit the changes (file removal). 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291782/gitignore-with-visual-studio-2013-not-working/34291878#34291878