# Git svn rebase results in conflicts

Tags: git, git-svn

I ran a `git filter-branch` on a rather large repo (~8000 commits) to remove certain binaries, but now when I do `git svn rebase` to keep my repo up to date, it results in a huge list of conflicts. I'm guessing it's because both commands involve rewriting the history.

Is there any way I can sync to Git from SVN after my filter-branch without these conflicts ? Will any future rebase also result in such problems too ? (I'm only syncing one way from SVN to Git)

Comment: As I see it there is nothing you can do to make `filter-branch` and `svn rebase` compatible. You're rewriting history which has a relationship to a remote. It would be a different story if you removed the remote after `filter-branch`, in that case it simply wouldn't matter, but as it stands I see __no way__ to make this work.

Comment: @Zeeker you should make this into an answer, I just realized that rewriting the history actually changes all the refs/objects which were previously pointing to an SVN commit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it there is nothing you can do to make `filter-branch` and `svn rebase` compatible. You're rewriting history which has a relationship to a remote. As such you change the commit hashes and make the mapping of the SVN rev_map utterly useless.

It would be a different story if you removed the remote after `filter-branch`, in that case it simply wouldn't matter, but as it stands I see **no way** to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

Commits which have been sent to SVN (via git svn dcommit) should not be further altered, as it results in conflicts as you saw.

In a git-only scenario, you could theoretically do a git push --force (although it's not encouraged if you work with others via that repo), but SVN doesn't allow that.

So, you cannot rewrite what's already been sent to the subversion server. If the binaries are on the subversion server, filter-branch wouldn't help you anyway. ALSO, if you use SVN tools on the server itself to remove the binaries, you would need a fresh checkout of the git copy - the git-svn data would be invalid at that point.

Only thing you can do now is reset your master branch to origin/trunk.

edit:
As for the emerging conflicts, my guess would be that the filter-branch messes up the relationships between git commits and svn revision numbers in $GIT_DIR/svn/**/.rev_map.* (see git-scm.com/docs/git-svn: CAVEATS/FILES).
Also, conflicts would naturally occur if there were changes from SVN side on files you deleted in your git copy.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned I'm only syncing one way from SVN to Git, there are no commits to SVN. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34879226/exclude-files-from-git-svn-clone)

Comment: My guess would be that the filter-branch messes up the $GIT_DIR/svn/*\*/.rev_map.*  (see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn: CAVEATS/ FILES).